# Index a file for only the first time and then ignore it

Tags: git

I create a new file in a project and add it to index. After committing it, I push the change to remote repo so that others can pull the new file. From now on, I don't want the file to be tracked any more. I know `git update-index --assume-unchanged` can ignore the file. But this only works for myself not for everyone in the project. Is there a way to tell everybody's git to ignore the file?

Comment: If you don't want it in the repository, don't put it in the repository.  What are you attempting to gain by putting it there to begin with?  Were you trying to share something with everyone?

Comment: The file is necessary for the project so it should be included in the repository. However, every time the project is built, the file will be changed. But these changes is meaningless. We don't want these changes to be indexed. @Makoto

Comment: You might also consider a server hook to reject pushes/merges which include your verboten file, if you can set that up. You can setup local hooks to do the same - the problem is that you have to make sure the local repos are running that hook to enforce it on that side and as I understand it, the hooks are not tracked in the repo in the .git repo (they would need to be outside and then moved into there after the clone, although maybe that could be part of a clone script that everyone uses).

Comment: @DavidN Thank you for the suggestion. But nearly every commit will include the file.

Comment: So when you say you dont want it to be tracked, I think you are really saying that you dont want people pushing back up a modified version of it, you just want them to get a copy, maybe make local changes, and then not push that. If so, people should know not to stage it. I think you are saying that because its tracked, if people do an add --update, they might unknowingly add it to the index and push it back. If so, again, the server side hook could reject.

Comment: Maybe one option is to have it as a hidden file (dot prefix) and then run a post fetch script that renames it to the undotted name that can then be overwritten by local changes, but that new name is not tracked and the original file is hidden, so they wouldnt know to update that. The problem then becomes that you need them to run this script after a fetch, which might be hard to enforce.

Comment: @DavidN you are right. I just want others to have a copy of the file but don't want them to push back any modification of the file from then on.

Comment: Did you review https://gist.github.com/canton7/1423106

Comment: @DavidN thank you for the link. It offers some interesting suggestions.